# glreadpixels pixels cut off and show black part, when using opengl es 3.0 PBO on Android 4.3

Tags: android, opengl-es, glreadpixels, opengl-es-3.0

i'm trying to do fast pixels reading by using PBO with opengl es 3.0 on Android 4.3.
my device resolution is 1280 * 720.

after called glReadPixels() and fetched pixels data, i encoded data to JPEG file.

problem is , original opengl image would be 1280 * 720, but jpeg is like, pixels [0~720, 0~720] rect is 90 degrees rotated opengl image, [721~1280, 0~720] is black (black seems to be junk data).

following is my code using pbo and glReadPixels().

PS: after some researches, i find

1. without using pbo, direct call glReadPixels(0, 0, 1280, 720, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer_ptr); , the pixels would be right. jpeg file is ok.
2. if i changed all 720 to 1280 in code, i can get whole opengl image with right side filled with black.

could you help to point out the problem?
any suggestion would be appreciated~
Thanks a lot!

```
glGenBuffers(1, &pbo_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_id);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 1280 * 720 * 3, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_READ);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

……
     // draw something with OpenGL ES 3.0

……

```
  glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_id);
  glReadPixels(0, 0, 1280, 720, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
  buffer_ptr = (GLubyte *)glMapBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, 1280 * 720 * 3, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
  glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

……
     // encode to jpeg

Comment: Looks like you're only mapping 3/4 of the buffer.

GL_RGBA is 4 bytes per pixel, you map 1280 * 720 * 3

Comment: sorry~ it's a typo when i paste code..  in my code, i use glGetIntegerv ( GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT,
        &readFormat );, the code i run is (0x1907)GL_RGB. i'll edit the pasted code~

Comment: The sequence you show suggests that you're using `buffer_ptr` to create the JPEG after the call to `glUnmapBuffer()`. Is that really what you're doing? That pointer would be invalid then.

Comment: yes, that part seems to be wrong, but I also tried to put encoding jpeg before glUnmapBuffer(), output jpeg is still the same.. :(